# Count overnight hours as one day

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a dataset where certain operations occur during the overnight hours which I'd like to attribute to the day before.

For example, anything happening between 2/23 8pm and 2/24 6am should be included in 2/23's metrics rather than 2/24. Anything from 6:01 am to 7:59pm should be counted in 2/24's metrics.

I've seen a few posts about decrementing time by 6 hours but that doesn't work in this case.

Is there a way to use an If function to specify that midnight-6am should be counted as **date**-1 rather than **date** without affecting the metrics for the 6am - 7:59pm hours?

Thanks in advance!  Also, a SQL newbie here so apologies if I have lots of followup questions.

Comment: Please check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Most important part is [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data so that I can replicate it and help you with the  requirement?

Comment: >=8pm(23) : <12am(24) = 23rd... (keep time)
>=12am(24) : <6am(24) = 23rd... (what do you want as the time?)
>=6am(24) : <8pm =24th = 24th (keep time)
just sounds like 6:6 is the day pattern

Comment: @enterprised1 "I've seen a few posts about decrementing time by 6 hours but that doesn't work in this case." Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Hello. If my answer addressed your question, please consider upvoting and accepting it. If not, let me know so that the answer can be improved. Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date_add` with -6 hours and then optionally cast the timestamp as a date.

> ```
> create table t (dcol datetime);
> insert into t values
> ('2022-02-25 06:01:00'),
> ('2022-02-25 06:00:00'),
> ('2022-02-25 05:59:00');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT CAST(DATE_ADD(dcol, INTERVAL -6 HOUR)AS DATE) FROM t;
> ```
>
> ```
> | CAST(DATE_ADD(dcol, INTERVAL -6 HOUR)AS DATE) |
> | :-------------------------------------------- |
> | 2022-02-25                                    |
> | 2022-02-25                                    |
> | 2022-02-24                                    |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=cc50d0f9b1996d3164c54b5d1cf5f2da)*

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, your requirement is the occurrences in a 6 AM to 6 AM day instead of a 12-12 day. You can achieve this by decreasing the time by 6 hours as shown in @Kendle’s answer. Another way to do it is to use an `IF` condition as shown below. Here, the date is decremented if the time is before 6 AM on each day and the new date is put in a new column.

**Query:**

```
SELECT
 IF
   (TIME(eventTime) <= "06:00:00",
     DATE_ADD(DATE(eventTime), INTERVAL -1 DAY),
     DATE(eventTime)) AS newEventTime
FROM
 `project.dataset.table`
ORDER BY
 eventTime;
```

**Output from sample data:**

[image]

As seen in the output, timestamps before 6 AM are considered for the previous day while the ones after are considered in the current day.